# A global function calls a mutating method of a protocol type. How can I get rid of the var tmp object?

Tags: swift, protocols, inout

this is my working code snippet.
But I want to get rid of the **var tmp** variable in the function **slide**.

```
protocol Moveable {
    mutating func move(to point: CGPoint)
}

class Car : Moveable {
    var point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 23, y: 42)
    func move(to point: CGPoint) {
        self.point = point
        print("Method move from class Car Point: \(point)")
    }
}

struct Shape : Moveable {
    var point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 23, y: 42)
    mutating func move(to point: CGPoint) {
       self.point = point
       print("Method move from struct Shape Point:\(point)")
    }
}

var prius: Car = Car()
var square: Shape = Shape()

func slide(slider: Moveable) {
    var tmp = slider  // <---- I want get rid of the tmp object.(
    tmp.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
}

slide(slider: prius)
slide(slider: square)
```

I have tried something like that, to avoid the var tmp:

```
func slide(slider: inout Moveable) {
    slider.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
}

slider(slider: prius) // <--- Compile Error
// Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'slider' is a 'let' constant
slider(slider: prius as (inout Moveable) // <--- Compile Error
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may work with this little change:

```
func slide<M: Moveable>(slider: inout M) {
    slider.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
}
```

Instead of asking for `Movable` we ask for a type conforming to `Movable`.

And call it like this:

```
slide(slider: &prius)
slide(slider: &square)
```

Comment: why the need for struct if we eventually mutate ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, `structs` can also be mutable, they only don't have `shared state` like `classes`(`objects`) do.

Comment: yes but this copies the struct internally instead of having only 1 ref type

Comment: @Sh_Khan, sometimes you need exactly that, if it wasn't useful there would be no value types in the languages. I prefer not to force usage of `classes` here.